# Реализация один товар ко многим категориям

Tags: php, mysql, sql

нужно переделать старую логику где у товара могла быть лишь одна категория и хранилась она в таблице `product`, в ячейке `category_id`, на логику связей "многие ко многим" где у товара может быть множество категорий.

По логике я понимаю, что нужно создать промежуточную таблицу, например `product_to_category` с столбцами `product_id` и `category_id`.

Но так как ранее подобного я еще не делал, то у меня вопрос в верности моего решения?
И достаточно ли его для данной реализации.

Буду рад вашей помощи, возможно я что то упускаю, либо не совсем верно понимаю.

Comment: верно. достаточно.

Comment: У вас останется единственная нерешённая проблема, которая заключается в том, что могут существовать продукты без категорий. Если это нормально, то больше ничего делать не надо(не забудьте выполнить миграцию данных и удалить старое поле)

Comment: @Ипатьев боагодарю за помощь!

Comment: @vp_arth , спасибо за ответ, в движке магазина не предусмотрено добавление продукта без выбора категории